# Read a text in .gz file when the .gz file is located in a .zip file

Tags: r, unzip

I have a large .zip file which contains thousands of .gz files. I would like to read the .txt in each .gz file, what should I do in the R environment? Many thanks for your help.

Best regards,
Songchao

Comment: Why not extract the zip file beforehand? I guess the difference in size would be neglectable unless there are also "non-gz" files in the zip-file.

Comment: It could be a solution. However, it takes too much time to zip a large .zip file and i have many this kind of climate data to deal with. Therefore, I would like to find a time-saving way.